# Regex Extract specific data between specific strings in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

Using regex in python 3.6.3 I am trying to extract scientific notation numbers associated with a specific start text and end text. From the following sample data:

```
Not_the_data : REAL[10] (randomtext := doesntapply) := [1.00000000e+000,-2.00000000e000,3.00000000e+000,4.00000000e+000,5.00000000e+000,6.00000000e+000
            ,7.00000000e+000,8.00000000e-000,9.00000000e+000,1.00000000e+001,1.10000000e+001];

This_data : REAL[2,27] (RADIX := Float) := [3.45982254e-001,9.80374157e-001,8.29904616e-001,1.57800000e+002,4.48320538e-001,6.20533180e+001
            ,1.80081348e+003,-8.93283653e+000,5.25826037e-001,2.16974407e-001,1.17304848e+002,6.82604387e-002
            ,3.76116596e-002,6.82604387e-002,3.76116596e-002];

Not_it_either : REAL[72] (randomtext := doesntapply) := [0.00000000e+000,-0.00000000e000,0.00000000e+000,0.00000000e+000,0.00000000e+000,0.00000000e+000];
```

I would want only the data in the "This_data" set:

```
['3.45982254e-001','9.80374157e-001','8.29904616e001','1.57800000e+002','4.48320538e-001','6.20533180e+001','1.80081348e+003','-8.93283653e+000','5.25826037e-001','2.16974407e-001','1.17304848e+002','6.82604387e-002','3.76116596e-002','6.82604387e-002','3.76116596e-002']
```

If I don't use the lookaround functions I can get all the numbers that match the scientific notation easily like this:

```
values = re.findall('(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+)',_DATA_,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```

But as soon as I add a lookahead function:

```
values = re.findall('(?<=This_data).*?(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+)+',_DATA_,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```

all but the first number in the desired set drop off. I have attempted multiple iterations of this using positive and negative lookahead and lookbehind on debugex to no avail.

My source file is 50k+ lines and the data set desired is 10-11k lines. Ideally I would like to capture my data set in one read through of my file.

How can I correctly use a lookahead or lookbehind function to limit my data capture to numbers that meet the format but only from the desired "This_Data" set?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have an easier time parsing the file one line at a time, skipping lines that don't meet the criteria.  It looks like each line ends with a semicolon, so you can use that as a way to break the parsing.

```
import re

PARSING = False
out = []

with open('path/to/file.data') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('This_data'):
            PARSING = True
        if PARSING:
            out.append(re.findall('(-?[0-9]+.[0-9]+e[+-][0-9]+)', line)
        # check if the line contains a semicolon to stop parsing
        if ';' in line:
            PARSING = False

# return the results:
out
```

Comment: James, Thanks for the awesome response time! This was my first question on here as I'm pretty new to coding and I was a bit worried I wasn't making any sense. I gave your code a shot and sure enough it worked! This definitely gets me through my task but I am still scratching my head a bit as to how to do it with fewer lines. I appreciate your help!

Comment: The first rule of coding is "make it work".  There are a number of ways to make this in fewer lines of code.  But until you reach a point where that is the limiting factor, getting your code up and running is more important.